# Magento 2.3 get row subtotal transactional email

Tags: magento2.3, email-templates, order-email

I want to load row subtotal inside the invoice transactional email.

Therefore I changed the following file (`/app/design/frontend/Theme/Theme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/invoice/default.phtml`)

And added the following: `<td><?php echo $_item->getRowTotal();?></td>`

But this does not work and does not load the row subtotal.

How can I get the row subtotal inside the invoice e-mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code

I just get row total below SKU using the below code and it works for me.

```
<P class="RowCode"><?= __("Row Totel")?>: <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getRowTotal())?>
```

Add above code in your

> /app/design/frontend/Theme/Theme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/invoice/default.phtml

Then try to flush Magento cache and check

Output:-

[image]